# Read multiple .xlsx files from a directory into separate Pandas data frames based on file name

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, glob

I want to load multiple xlsx files with varying structures from a directory and assign these their own data frame based on the file name.  I have 30+ files with differing structures but for brevity please consider the following:

3 excel files `[wild_animals.xlsx, farm_animals_xlsx, domestic_animals.xlsx]`

I want to assign each with their own data frame so if the file name contains 'wild' it is assigned to `wild_df`, if farm then `farm_df` and if domestic then `dom_df`. This is just the first step in a process as the actual files contain a lot of 'noise' that needs to  be cleaned depending on file type etc  they file names will also change on a weekly basis with only a few key markers staying the same.

My assumption is the glob module is the best way to begin to do this but in terms of taking very specific parts of the file extension and using this to assign to a specific df I become a bit lost so any help appreciated.

I asked a similar question a while back but it was part of a wider question most of which I have now solved.

Answer (score 3):

I would parse them into a dictionary of DataFrame's:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('/path/to/*.xlsx')
dfs = {}

for f in files:
    dfs[os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]] = pd.read_excel(f)
```

then you can access them as a normal dictionary elements:

```
dfs['wild_animals']
dfs['domestic_animals']
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You nee to get all xlsx files, than using comprehension dict, you can access to any elm

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = 'Your_path'
extension = 'xlsx'
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

{elm:pd.ExcelFile(elm) for elm in result}
```

Comment: Thanks - this gives me what I need in terms of a dictionary of files but if I wanted to access and create a dataframe called wild from only files with the name "wild" in how would I go about this from what you have given so far? 

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness wanted to show the solution I ended up using, very close to Khelili suggestion with a few tweaks to suit my particular code including not creating a DataFrame at this stage

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as excel
import glob



#setting up path

path = 'data_inputs'
extension = 'xlsx'
os.chdir(path)
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#Grouping files - brings multiple files of same type together in a list 

wild_groups = ([s for s in files if "wild" in s])
domestic_groups = ([s for s in files if "domestic" in s])

#Sets up a dictionary associated with the file groupings to be called in another module 
file_names = {"WILD":wild_groups, "DOMESTIC":domestic_groups}
...
```